# Why is there an extra variable in the Backbone model constructor?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
  var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
    var attrs = attributes || {};
    options || (options = {});
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
    this.attributes = {};
    if (options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
    if (options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};
    attrs = _.defaults({}, attrs, _.result(this, 'defaults'));
    this.set(attrs, options);
    this.changed = {};
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  };
```

there is no need for

```
    var attrs = attributes || {};
```

as attributes is not used any where else.  It could be treated the same way as options.  Just change the constructor argument to `attrs` and get rid of `arguments`.

```
  var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attrs, options) {
    attrs  || (attrs  = {});
```

Note that there are 3 attribute like variables.  The passed in argument `attributes`, the instance variable `this.attributes` and also the local and possibly extra local variable `attrs`.

Answer (score 1):

What you've asserted is not quite right. The `attributes` hash is copied to `attrs` which is later modified in-place; however, the initial argument `attributes` is passed unadulterated to `initialize.apply`.

You could also write `this.initialize.call(this, attributes, options)` to make this more explicit.

`attrs` is a mutable* copy of `attributes`. `options` is only ever read, not written, so a copy is not needed.

---

* everything is mutable in JavaScript, but this code behaves as though the arguments are immutable.

Comment: This isn't quite right. `attrs` is a reference to the same object as `attributes`, so the update in place of `attrs` will also affect `attributes`. If the code was `var attrs = _.clone(attributes) || {};` then you would be correct.

Comment: @WillDemaine `_.defaults({}...` takes care of the cloning

Comment: There is still no guarantee that attributes is unchanged because it is passed to `this.parse` (as attrs) before `_.defaults` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Often times, code will include variables which are not strictly necessary, but are useful for improving readability or to reduce confusion. In this case, it is likely done to distinguish the locally scoped variable from the `this.attributes` property of the model.